# Unknown argument in self invoke function

Tags: javascript

I have found the following self-invoke function syntax:

```
var data = (0, foo)();
function foo(){
   return "a";
}
```

but i did not get what is the meaning of 0(**zero**) here. Can anyone explain it to me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think the zero does anything in this instance as `(foo)()` accomplishes the same. So does `("hello", foo)()`, and `({}, foo)()`. However, it may be worth looking into the [*comma operator*](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/)

Comment: Exactly, a "comma-separated-list-of-statements" just returns what is returned by the last item in the list. For example `x = (2, 3, "Hi")` will set the value `"Hi"` to `x`

Comment: i have seen this syntax in many npm. if it is worthless then why all using it ?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinoin, this is a pointless use of the [*comma operator*](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/).

*[@techfoobar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/921204/techfoobar)* correctly states that:

> A "comma-separated-list-of-statements" just returns what is returned by the last item in the list. For example `x = (2, 3, "Hi")` will set the value `"Hi"` to `x`.

```js
function foo(){
   return "a";
}

// The following all return 'a'
console.log(('hello', foo)());
console.log((null, foo)());
console.log((true, foo)());
console.log((undefined, foo)());
console.log((0, foo)());
console.log((1, foo)());
console.log(({}, foo)());
```

Answer (score 1):

The 0 is completely optional, what this syntax does is, it evals every member and returns the last.

In this case you have: (0, foo)
It will eval 0 to 0, eval foo to a function, return it and call it with the last ()

You can simply call

```
(foo)()
```

Or you can create some steps to it

This will alert and then invoke foo

```
function a () {
    alert(1)
}

(a(), foo)()
```

and this will simply alert and return foo as a function, so you can call it later

```
var f = (a(), foo)
f()
```

It may have a very specific use for conditional scopes or variables to which I don't know

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, Function call with comma operator maybe a programming habit. It provides us with space for thinking deeply as we make a function call.

the result of function calls like `(foo)();` and `(0,foo)();` are the same.
But the latter way will let you think about what else to do BEFORE foo was called.
you can replace the 0 with `doSomething()` what you should do.

Comment: I don't agree with what you sair, you can solve this with a comment. But I liked your answer.. hahahha